# How to find LDAP connection string?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008, connection-string, bind

This is my program. I am not able to bind. I dont know what is the problem. I think there is a problem with connection string. How to find the LDAP connection string?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <wchar.h>
    #include <objbase.h>
    #include <activeds.h>
    #include <AdsHlp.h>

    using namespace std;
    const IID IID_IADs = {0xFD8256D0, 0xFD15, 0x11CE, {0xAB,0xC4,0x02,0x60,0x8C,0x9E,0x75,0x53}};
    int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
    {
    IADs *pObject;
    HRESULT hr;
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
            hr = ADsOpenObject(L"ldap://server1",L"cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com",L"secret",
                ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, 
                IID_IADs,
                (void**)&pObject);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
    cout<<"Success";
    pObject->Release();
    }
    else
    cout<<"Unsuccessful";

    CoUninitialize();
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should edit you answer and specify the error tou met.

Comment: I am not getting error. When I run the program I am getting "Unsuccessful".

Comment: Then you need to print an error code of some kind. Just telling us what your own error message was isn't in the least useful, and neither is 'not able to bind'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the connection string in C will be like in C++, but for C++ we have to set username and password in the connection string like this:

```
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://CN=Manager,DC=maxcrc,DC=com",
                   "username",
                   "password",
                   ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, 
                   IID_IADs,
                   (void**) &pObject);
```

Comment: i have a doubt. what should i enter in username and password attributes?   Is the the login username and password?

Comment: During the log in screen i see VIRTUAL/Administrator asking for a password. Should I have to enter "VIRTUAL/Administrator" as username and my login password as password in those fields.

Comment: Yes, you have to use login username and password. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I never use ADSI COM object from 'C', but when I use it from PowerShell I met an error if I don't use capital letters for 'LDAP' in the connexion URL (PowerShell is not case sensitive). Have a look to [LDAP ADsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) all the URLs begin by 'LDAP' in capital letters.